# Algorithm to detect flat tyre by comparing wheels speeds

Tags: wheels, abs

So ABS systems are capable of detecting a flat tyre, because it will roll a bit faster (because of smaller diameter).

What could be speed difference, needed to detect such fault? Do ABS systems only detect it when driving on smooth straight road, when wheels are supposed to roll at same speed?

I have speed sensors on each wheel, so I want to implement same feature. I just don't know what I should consider when taking measurements.

Comment: I would imagine that a car with a fancy system that detects flats likely also has an encoder that measures the angle of the steering wheel, such that speed difference from cornering can be cancelled out mathematically. I don't have a source to back this up, though.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the difference in rolling diameter between a new tire and a worn but legal one.

Then a tire going flat will be smaller.

But also, some 4 wheel drive systems do not tolerate a significant difference in diameter...